# Driving Voice Navigation turn-by-turn (do not take Source as current position, entered by user only) using Google Map API?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, navigation, navigator

Can I pass Source (not as current position) and destination to Google Map? Here is my code which only take destination and open up navigation into google map.

Can we pass source and destination to map entered by user and source should not consider as current position?

**Navigation.java**

```
package com.example.hacker_machine.navigationdrawer;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; 
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Navigation extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.navigation);

         Button navigation = (Button)findViewById
                            (R.id.btnSourceDestNavigation);
         navigation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {

                   String __dest__ = "Taronga Zoo, Sydney Australia";
                  __dest__=__dest__.replaceAll(" ","+");
                  Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q="
                  + __dest__+"&mode=d");
                  Intent mapIntent = 
                        new  Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                                gmmIntentUri);
                    mapIntent.setPackage(
                      "com.google.android.apps.maps");
                     startActivity(mapIntent);
        }
    });
}
}
```

**navigation.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout    xmlns:android=
         "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
         android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
         android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
         android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
         tools:context=".Navigation">

         <Button
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="Naviagation"
              android:textStyle="bold"
              android:id="@+id/btnSourceDestNavigation"
              android:layout_marginTop="50dp"/>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

**Android Menifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.mapnavigation">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".Navigation">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"    />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
</manifest>
```

Please give me hint or code snippet which can help to modify current code to target code (it should take source by user only, not as current position as source).

Anyone has done same as before please provide link to that -
any useful resource also welcome.

Comment: You need to understand what you are asking. You are using the Google Maps App to do turn-by-turn navigation. IF there is no API to do what you ask, and its not your app - it isn't possible, or at least not without the risk of breaking in the next app update (which you have no control over). Pretty costs money so unless you want to write your own navigation app you will have to look at the apps `they don't look so great as good as google navigator itself`

Comment: If you are on the edge of being banned due to past votes on your questions, you can increase your score (and thus reduce the likelihood of a question ban) by answering some questions.